# Maven Bukkit Server Plugin EventHandler

Tags: maven

I have following code. I want to make plugin which send player name of attacker when is attacked. Bud it isn't working.. Any solution?

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent event) {
    final Entity entity = event.getEntity();
    if (entity instanceof Player) {
    Player player = (Player)entity;
    player.sendMessage("You have been damaged.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with a friend or with a cracked account?

First of all you used the wrong Event. `EntityDamageEvent` means, that an entity ( e.g a Player )does damage. Simply use `EntityDamageByEntityEvent`.
And the entity that damgages something is a Player in your code + your
 message is `("You have been damaged")`..this is senceless actually, because like I said before, that Player is the `DAMAGER` and not the `DAMAGED`. 
Much better Code would be:

```
@EventHandler

public void onEntityDamageByEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    final Entity entity = event.getDamager();
    if (entity instanceof Player) {
    Player player = (Player)entity;
    final Entity entity2 = event.getEntity();
     if(entity2 instanceof Player){
    Player player2 = (Player)entity2;
     player2.sendMessage("You got damaged by " + player.getName());
        }
}
```

}